# How to set the length of char(9) in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm working with sql server and I need to insert into a string (defined as NVARCHAR(1000)) multiple tabulation.

The problem is that char(9) introduces too much spaces and I'm looking for a way to set the length of the tabulation if it is possible.

I make an example:

```
SELECT t.name + char(9) + t.surname + char(9) + t.number
FROM table t
```

print something like this (immagine that _ is a space):

Luk_________Franklin_________34512334

David_______King_____________45

but what I need is:

Luk____Franklin____34512334

David__King________45

I know that the solution could be for example: "Use SPACE(4)", but I need the tabulation because I put the content of that column in a label in a proprietary software. This means that all the name, surname and number should be aligned and only the tabulation (I think) can help me.

I hope to have explained myself well.

Comment: Presentation formatting is not SQL Server's job and consequently you will find it increasingly difficult and kludgy to keep tying to use it for this purpose that it was not intended for.  I strongly suggest that you use any of the many, many different tools, utilities and facilities that were expressly designed for this.  Pull the data from SQL Server into Excel, VB, C#, Access, etc. which are all better choices for text formatting.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (will add 5 spaces):

```
DECLARE @Space char(5)
SET @Space = '     '

SELECT t.name + @Space + t.surname + @Space + t.number
FROM table t
```

Or alternatively also with 5 spaces:

```
SELECT t.name + '     ' + t.surname + '     ' + t.number
FROM table t
```

**EDIT:** After understanding your needs better. This will make each column a fixed length and add spaces as needed.

```
SELECT Cast(t.name AS CHAR(9)) + 
       Cast(t.surname AS CHAR(9)) + 
       Cast(t.number AS CHAR(9))
FROM table t
```

Comment: In this way the problem is that all name, surname and number in all the rows are not aligned. Since all the name (and surname) have different length.

Comment: @Anthos89 See edit. Set CHAR value to length needed.

Comment: Although this should work (maybe temporarily), I agree with @RBarryYoung - your app should take care of this formatting